# inline-block containing video tag chooses wrong height in DOCTYPE HTML mode

Tags: html, flexbox

In quirks mode the below works as I'd like it to:

```
<div id = "container" style = "display:inline-block; position: relative;">
    <video id = "d" controls src = "movie.mov" style = "height:100%" />
</div>
```

The movie file fits the vertical contents of the page (meaning the height:100% is interpreted to mean the parent of container I suppose), and the width adjusts proportionally. Meanwhile, the container fits all of them. However, the second I go into DOCTYPE HTML and leave quirk's mode, the movie fills its entire intrinsic height (meaning it either ignore height:100% or interprets 100% of own size) and thus the container also becomes that large. I basically want to replicate the quirk's mode behavior.

Comment: have you tried setting height to the surrounding parent (div)?